# SpringBootTest - generate test in empty test class

Tags: spring, junit5, spring-boot-test, spring-annotations

I want to create an annotation that will allow me to generate tests with spring context, taking generation information from a file from resourse and at the same time raising test containers. Something similar to cucumber.

I tried to write my own test engine where I started doing this but ran into problems. The custom test engine does not support extensions; the spring context there must be launched manually, which is why the task looks very complicated. I was also thinking of writing my own annotation processor where i would insert tests during compilation. I want to find some simple way to generate tests.

for exapmle:

```
@MyAnnotation("first.json")
class AnnotationTest {
}
```

[execution example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SllD.png)

Comment: Your question is too vague to get a good answer IMO. Add one or two examples of what you want to achieve so that anyone suggesting an approach has something concrete to answer.